# Python/mySQL : ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am using mysql 5.7.21,  Connector/Python 2.0.4, Python 3.6.3

I defined a table in my python script,

```
TABLES['report'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `report` ("
    "  `t` varchar(4) NOT NULL,"
    "  `s` varchar(50) NOT NULL,"
    "  `d` varchar(10) NOT NULL,"
    "  `v` int(12) NOT NULL,"
    "  `g` varchar(12) NOT NULL,"
    "  `q` varchar(12) NOT NULL,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`t`)"   
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
```

and have created it successfully in the db.

But, when I tried to insert the following data

```
data= ('1111', 'xxxxxxxxxx-cc', 'AsOf20170630', '81785000', 'xxxx-cc', '2017Q2')
```

into table with

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO report (t, s, d, v, g, q) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, $s)", data)
```

I got an error,

```
ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: why `'81785000'` while v is `int` you can give `81785000` like this right ? and the last `$s` or `%s` ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The last $s is a typo, it should be %s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by the following :

in that `values` the last `$s` change to `%s` 
and if that not works you can try by changing
`'81785000'` to `81785000` because v is `int`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO report (t, s, d, v, g, q) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, **%s**)", data)

The last $s should be replaced with %s

In python $s I do not think it's valid to handle strings, because the query you're running is a string.